# Node js Express Framework - regex not working

Tags: regex, node.js, express

I am trying to use Reg Ex with an Express route in my Node app.  I want the route to match the path '/' or '/index.html' but instead it matches EVERYTHING :(

Here's my route.

```
app.get(/\/(index.html)?/, function(req, res){
    res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    res.send('Hello from node!');
});
```

How can I get this regular expression to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
app.get(/^\/(index\.html)?$/, function(req, res){
  res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.send('Hello from node!');
});
```

Without the `$`, anything following the first `/` can still match, and the `index.html` is just an optional prefix. Without the `^`, it will also match `/something/index.html`.

Answer (score 1):

Pass a regular expression as string.

```
app.get('/(index\.html)?', function(req, res){
    res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    res.send('Hello from node!');
});
```

Comment: It also matches `/index.html/` because it's a pattern and not a regex (I wasn't the one that downvoted, though).

Comment: This answer is also good :)  It is nice sometimes to allow that trailing slash.  Thanks!